# Pandas - populate empty columns in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df_temp` where I want to create empty columns and populate them in a for loop. This is what I have:

```
df_temp['Rendimento'] = .0
df_temp['Local']=''

for row in df_temp.iterrows():
    (index, row_contents) = row
    if row_contents['Jogos_Casa'] > row_contents['Jogos_Fora']:
        row_contents['Rendimento'] = (row_contents['Media_Fora']*100)/row_contents['Media_Casa']
        row_contents['Local'] = 'Casa'
    elif row_contents['Jogos_Fora'] > row_contents['Jogos_Casa']:
        row_contents['Rendimento'] = (row_contents['Media_Casa']*100)/row_contents['Media_Fora']
        row_contents['Local'] = 'Fora'
    print (row_contents)
```

When I `print (row_contents)`, I get:

```
Atleta           Salah
Time             Liverpool
Posicao            ATA
Media_Casa        3.32
Jogos_Casa          13
Media_Fora        3.51
Jogos_Fora          16
Jogos_Total         29
Media_Diff       -0.19
Rendimento     94.5869
Local             Fora
```

But when I print `df_temp`, newly created `'Rendimento'` and `'Local'` columns are empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: From docs `You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.` this might be the reason.

Comment: this is not the way to use the api, use `.loc` or `np.where/np.select` there are a plethora of answers on here showing one how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.select`:

```
import numpy as np

choices_local = ['Casa','Fora']
choices_Rendim = [(df['Media_Fora']*100)/df['Media_Casa'],(df['Media_Casa']*100)/df['Media_Fora']]
conditions=[df['Jogos_Fora'].lt(df['Jogos_Casa']), df['Jogos_Casa'].lt(df['Jogos_Fora'])]

df['Local']=np.select(conditions, choices_local, default='')
df['Rendimento']=np.select(conditions, choices_Rendim, default='')
```

The thing to consider here is the default case, that will be when `row['Jogos_Fora']== row['Jogos_Casa']`, so you can put your desired result when this happens.

---

**Example:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Jogos_Casa':[4,2,3,4,5],'Jogos_Fora':[1,3,5,1,7],'Media_Casa':[1,2,3,4,7],'Media_Fora':[4,3,1,1,1]})
print(df)
choices_local = ['Casa','Fora']
choices_Rendim = [(df['Media_Fora']*100)/df['Media_Casa'],(df['Media_Casa']*100)/df['Media_Fora']]
conditions=[df['Jogos_Fora'].lt(df['Jogos_Casa']), df['Jogos_Casa'].lt(df['Jogos_Fora'])]

df['Local']=np.select(conditions, choices_local, default='')
df['Rendimento']=np.select(conditions, choices_Rendim, default='')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
   Jogos_Casa  Jogos_Fora  Media_Casa  Media_Fora
0           4           1           1           4
1           2           3           2           3
2           3           5           3           1
3           4           1           4           1
4           5           7           7           1


df(after np.select)
   Jogos_Casa  Jogos_Fora  Media_Casa  Media_Fora Local         Rendimento
0           4           1           1           4  Casa              400.0
1           2           3           2           3  Fora  66.66666666666667
2           3           5           3           1  Fora              300.0
3           4           1           4           1  Casa               25.0
4           5           7           7           1  Fora              700.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using apply method -

```
def my_func(record):
    if record['Jogos_Casa'] > record['Jogos_Fora']:
        record['Rendimento'] = (record['Media_Fora']*100)/record['Media_Casa']
        record['Local'] = 'Casa'
    elif record['Jogos_Fora'] > record['Jogos_Casa']:
        record['Rendimento'] = (record['Media_Casa']*100)/record['Media_Fora']
        record['Local'] = 'Fora'
    return record

tmp_df = tmp_df.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```